# Add Service Worker to Create React App Project

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, freshdesk

I am installing a notification system called Subscribers with a project built with create react app. They ask the developer to download their service worker and include it in the root directory of the project. I have never had to install / use a service worker before, which is most likely the root of my misunderstanding.

How do you add a service worker into the root directory of a React project? The instructions say the service worker should appear in the root directory as https://yoursite.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js. In an attempt to register that URL, I included a service worker under src/index.js:

```
import Environment from './Environment'

export default function LocalServiceWorkerRegister() {
    const swPath = `${Environment.getSelfDomain()}/firebase-messaging-sw.js`;
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath).then(function(registration) {
          // Registration was successful
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          // registration failed :(
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
}
```

In production, I receive a 404 error. I have tried placing the firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the root directory, and under the src folder. Same error each time.

Here are the instructions from Subscribers:
https://subscribers.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/35000013054-diy-installation-instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `public` folder is the provided 'escape hatch' for adding assets from outside of the module system.
From the [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system):

> If you put a file into the public folder, it will **not** be processed by Webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use a special variable called `PUBLIC_URL`

So, once copied to the `public` folder, you would reference the file like this:

```js
import Environment from './Environment'

export default function LocalServiceWorkerRegister() {
    const swPath = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/firebase-messaging-sw.js`;
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath).then(function(registration) {
          // Registration was successful
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          // registration failed :(
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
}
```